# CSS3 double background image not showing in firefox but it does in chrome?

Tags: css, firefox, sass

http://prosepticwp.cloud-2.co.uk/drainage-services/septic-tank-replacement/ - The banner image shows correctly in Chrome but not at all in FireFox?

I have tried to get it to work with firefox inspector but no luck.

```css
background: url(../images/Drainage-services-img.png)right top no-repeat/contain,linear-gradient(180deg,#17156d 0,#383681 100%);
```

The error: Invalid property value.

Comment: please provide a working snippet

Comment: try this `background: url('../images/Drainage-services-img.png') right top/contain no-repeat, linear-gradient(180deg,#17156d 0%, #383681 100%);`

Comment: can you accept my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox may not accept this lineup. You can try using standard spelling. Like this:

```
background: url('../images/Drainage-services-img.png') right top/contain no-repeat, linear-gradient(180deg,#17156d 0%, #383681 100%);
```